# I want to use awk to delete every nth line starting at line 27

Tags: awk

I have a large text file, it has a header that has 27 lines.  I want to keep the header in the new file, but then on line 28 where the data starts I only want to keep every 10th line.

So my new file will look just like my original file where it will include 27 lines of header, but instead of all of the data being there only every 10th line will be included in the new file.

Ive been trying use 'awk', ive also tried 'sed' i can get it to give me every 10th line, but i can't get it to include the lines of header, i.e. start on line 28 and then give every 10th line

Comment: Try `sed '28~10d' file > newfile` with GNU `sed`. If you want Line 28 to stay replace with `38~10d`.

Comment: It's not clear if you want line 28 present in the output or not. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Use values like 5 and 3 instead of 27 and 10 to create the [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR<=27{print;next} ++count%10==0{print;count=""}'  Input_file
```

Or in case you want to make it more generic, so adding variables here, one could change variables values here and get as per need results too.

```
awk -v lines_till_print="27"  -v nth_line_print="10" '
FNR<=lines_till_print{
  print
  next
}
++count%nth_line_print==0{
  print
  count=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks, you first example did the trick.  Now how can i make this a python3 command?

Answer (score 0):

To print every 3rd line after a 5 line header:

```
$ seq 20 | awk -v h=5 -v r=3 'NR<=h || !((NR-h)%r)'
1
2
3
4
5
8
11
14
17
20
```

or if you want the first line after the 5 line header printed:

```
$ seq 20 | awk -v h=6 -v r=3 'NR<=h || !((NR-h)%r)'
1
2
3
4
5
6
9
12
15
18
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ seq 20 | awk -v h=5 -v r=3 'NR<=h || ((NR-h)%r)==1'
1
2
3
4
5
6
9
12
15
18
```

Change the variable values to suit.